# Secure Bluetooth Service

Tags: security, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Say that there are multiple devices installed in a public space and broadcast a BLE connection for assigned workers/technicians to be able to communicate with the device. What security measures could be taken in order to prevent unwanted users from connecting to them?

Only solution that comes to mind is a Pass Key but there is a limited number of combinations. Thus the actual pass key might be guessed after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming there are an unbounded number of authorized users (there's no short, fixed list of devices that you could bond).

A typical solution to this kind of problem is a challenge-response based on a shared secret. As one example design (this design has some flaws that I'll discuss afterwards):

- The client and the device share a pre-arranged 128-bit random key
- The client makes an unauthenticated, encrypted ("Just Works") connection
- The device generates a random 128-bit challenge which the client reads
- The client encrypts the challenge with the key and returns it
- The device verifies that the encryption is correct, and authenticates the connection

For low-security situations, this is decent, very easy to implement, and does not require a lot of processing power for the device or any extra hardware. It does have problems, however.

First, Just Works encryption is not that hard to brute force and MiTM. If the device is accessed often by workers, and an attacker has some dedication, this will fail.

If the device has a display that can be shielded from view, then an improved design would use Passkey Entry to perform the initial pairing, and then use challenge-response for authentication:

- Device generates a 6-digit pin
- Worker enters 6 digit pin into client
- Client connects to the device using Passkey Entry w/ pin
- Continue as above with random challenge/response to authenticate

If the device has an NFC chip, this can be be made easier on the user by using NFC to distribute pairing key, and then using shared-secret to authenticate. (This is called OOB or "out of band" pairing.)

The key point in all of this is that you first create as secure a connection as you can to prevent eavesdropping and MiTM. You then, as a separate issue, authenticate the client using a shared secret.

One possible disadvantage of this system is that anyone with the shared secret can pretend to the the device. From your description, that doesn't feel like a major problem, but if it were, you can avoid that by using public-private keys, such that the device held a private key and all the clients held the public key. The public key in this situation is a secret, however. (You could go further and issue client keys and do mutual auth, but that is likely overkill unless your device is pretty powerful and network connected.)

Comment: Hi @Rob Napier, first of all thank you for the well informed reply. I really appreciate your time and effort. Technically any PIN can be 'brute forced' I guess, perhaps upon detecting a number of unsuccessful pairing attempts, the device could disable the BLE broadcasting for a definite period? This way unsuccessful pairing could be deterred. How would you suggest that the device exchanges the 128 bit key? Upon pairing through a UART string perhaps?

Unfortunately the device does not have a display which can show the PIN.

Can you elaborate further about the public-private keys please?

Comment: The 128-bit key would be baked into the device and into the clients. It's a pre-shared secret. Using public-private keys for this is a somewhat complex topic if you're not familiar with public-private key systems generally (if you are, then you implement challenge response the same way: the device provides some challenge, and the client signs it in response; all clients share the same key).

Comment: I know you can't use the screen, but in the 6-digit PIN design, each connection gets a new PIN, so the expected number of trials to collide is 1M (it would be 500k if the PIN were static, but this isn't a search problem, it's a collision problem). At 10 attempts per second, that's over a day to brute force it. If you introduce a small delay into the challenge creation, you could probably push this to a week. Far from impossible, so it depends on what you're protecting. If you're willing to introduce an arbitrarily long delay in the connection, you can of course make this as secure as you like.